# Set background color of a box with predefined width

Tags: color, boxes, minipage

I would like to have something like a minipage with colored background, i.e. a box where you can predefine the width and the background color. My attempt

```
\colorbox{green}{\begin{minipage}{\slwidth}
Some text
\end{minipage}}
```

lead to a box which was a bit wider than the original minipage. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `\fboxsep0pt` before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set `\fboxsep=0pt` to avoid the extra padding around the minipage. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\colorbox{green}{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
  Some text
\end{minipage}}

\fboxrule.2pt\fboxsep-.2pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
Some text
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a group the setting will be local.

Comment: @egreg True. I am not too sure what the OP wants though, as a colorbox without a bit of padding does not look very sexy.

Comment: Possibly a very thin padding is better.

Comment: I works well; the aim is to produce boxes of given width which can be converted to images by the "preview"-package.

Answer (score 2):

Test this. Wrapfigure is optional, but I like adding it and I like that it works!

```
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{7cm}  
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.95\linewidth} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!5,colframe=green!40!black,title=In short]
Example text ... blabla         
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{minipage}  
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Why do you use a wrapfigure? Does it really solve the 'old' question? A full example with some screenshot would be appreciated!